# How to setup Azure web service with sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I wonder how can I connect my web role to existing SQL database ? Under settings tab in properties of web role I've tried to add new setting with connection string to my database, but when i try to Login (I'm using asp.net Identity, and using code first migrations I've successfully seeded DB), I get this error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

So what is correct way to connect my DB to web role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was stupid problem with my connection string, I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the dashboard for your SQL Azure database. Click on the "Manage allowed IP addresses" link.

Make sure that the Windows Azure Services are set to YES under allowed services.

All The SQL Databases on Azure require a whitelist for IP ranges that can access them.

Comment: Thanks, but YES was selected